# Employee schedule entity relationship

Tags: java, mysql, hibernate, orm

I need to implement schedule, and this schedule should be individual for any account. That means, it can be fixed (5 working, Sa and Su - days off), or it can be floating (one day working, one day off). Also, each day can have it's own set of working hours spans.
Also there are events binded to each working hour span.
So it's complicating.
Main goal - to show date picker on front end, preventing user from picking dates on day-offs or on hours already having attached events.
I decided to store just pattern in MySQL + events table with exact date and ref to working hour span.
The whole entities relationship looks like that now:

```
Account->Schedule

Schedule->WorkingWeeks (number: 1 means every 1st week is working and no weeks-off, 2 means 1st week is off, 2nd working, than again off etc., Days)

WorkingWeek->Days (number: 1 means every 1st day is working and no days-off, 2 means 1st day is off, 2nd working, than again off etc.)

Day->Hours (just list of hours like 9-10,11-12, so 10-11 is break in work)
```

So there will be several joins and last join will be with events table to show just hours that don't have events for that particular date.

All that will be passed to frontend, where JS will buld a date picker from it.
Is that sane approach at all or should I use something else? I am a novice, so I'd appreciate any help...

Answer (score 2):

Your data model can really be whatever works for your business use case.

Sometimes it's useful to have the data model closely align the business case just to ease the translation between data fetch and the visual/business use cases.  Other times, it is useful to try and model the data structures more genericly in order to allow a more flexible design to potential downstream change.

I will however urge you to consider the idea of overlaying multiple schedules.

For example, it may be useful to define a holiday schedule globally that includes hours/dates where time is completely unavailable because staff are off, etc.  It's useful to have this defined once rather than per account as a single change can be replicated across the data model.

Then to display the composite schedule view, simply get all associated schedules, including the global ones and mark the appropriate hours available/unavailable as needed based on the data from the data model.

Comment: Thank you for this comment. Yes, you are right, there definitely will be global vacations table to be able to set, for example, national holidays etc.  What I am really anxious about is the number of joins here: I see at least 5 joins now. This number of joins each time the page is rendered might slow down the MySQL db or be very slow. Or it's ok?

Comment: @Battle_Slug Unless you're at the point to test whether those joins with adequate volumes of data is actually a performance bottleneck, I would not be too concerned.  It can be tweaked later to pre-aggregate the data if needed.

Comment: Thank you, will see then. I'll try to implement this way and test